# Printed barcode isn't clear (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I need barcode print module in my app but can't figure it out how to print barcodes properly. It looks like it's resolution is too low.
I'm using [Zen Barcode](https://barcoderender.codeplex.com/). As you can see per attached photo, top barcode is printed from printer's software, proving printer is ok, bottom picture is printed from my code:

[WPF]

```
        <Grid x:Name="_printSerialBcode" Margin="9" Visibility="Visible">
            <Image x:Name="serial_bcode1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2"/>
        </Grid>
```

[C#]

```
    private void printJob()
    {
        // use printer we need
        SetDefaultPrinter("Brother QL-700");
        //draw barcodes
        BarcodeDraw bc = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;

        Bitmap serial_bitmap = (Bitmap)bc.Draw(serial, 20);

        ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();

        //generate bitmap
        serial_bcode1.Source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(serial_bitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        var dlg = new PrintDialog();

        //print main label
        dlg.PrintTicket.CopyCount = 1; // number of copies
        dlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        dlg.PrintVisual(_printSerialBcode, "Barcode");

        //change default printer to original one
        SetDefaultPrinter(defaultPrinter);
    }
```

[image: Test barcodes]

Comment: Are you setting `SnapToDevicePixels` anywhere?

Comment: no difference. i use it on Image, also tried on grid

Comment: Have you tried passing in the actual size of the barcode to `CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap` instead of `Int32Rect.Empty`?

Comment: try setting [`BitmapScalingMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [`EdgeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.edgemode(v=vs.110).aspx) against image `<Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality"/>`. You might want to disable anti aliasing in such case

Comment: Instead of using Zen Barcode, try just using a BarCode Font.  You can "Write" the text onto an image at very high resolution and have it crystal clear at whatever size you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as recommended by Don, I used Barcode Font, much easier and high quality print!
I'm using [IDAutomation](http://www.bizfonts.com/free/)

Comment: How did you solve that issue? Can u please share it! Now I'm getting trouble with that. I'm doing: `e.Graphics.DrawString("25 characters", font, brush, 0, 0)`  but result is like yours. Any barcode scanner could not scan.

Comment: just use that font, but remember to put code between * and it will work

Comment: I've used it's printing well but not scannable :( . Max characters are 28 and thermal printer resolution is 203 DPI.