# I am looking for graphics classes in wpf which are present in window form

Tags: wpf

this is my code and i want to convert it in wpf but having too much difficulties. please some one help me in this.
the problem was first to find the replacement of bitmap which i found as bitmap image but now i was unable to found a class which replaced graphics
here is my code:

```
string barcode = textBox1.Text;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 40, 150);
            // i changed bitmap to this
            BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                Font oFont = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 20);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush white = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.FillRectangle(white, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", oFont,black,point);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
                    pictureBox1.Height = bitmap.Height;
                    pictureBox1.Width = bitmap.Width;
                }

                sd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sd.Filter = "PNG File|*.png";
                if(sd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image.Save(sd.FileName, 
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                }
```

Comment: Instead of letting us guess, could you please explain what your code is supposed to do, or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If i need to go for a different approach then also let me know please i am badly stuck in this thing :(

Comment: It seems you're just drawing text on a white background. Why do you have a bitmap at all?

Comment: actually i am trying to generate a barcode. so i generated one in window forms but when i tried it in wpf then i got stuck in these classes and libraries things.

Comment: Still unclear why there is a bitmap. You're drawing text, apparently with a barcode font. There doesn't seem to be any need for a bitmap. You may read up about the basics in WPF, i.e. how to use a TextBlock with a special font.

Comment: Actually i was following a tutorial and that lead me in this bitmap thing.

Comment: so you are saying that what i am trying to do can be done by using a simple textbox with special fonts?

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't actually need a bitmap, e.g. for writing an image file or something like that.

Comment: Actually yes, i am drawing a barcode on a picture box and saving that image as a png on my computer.

Comment: I am sorry for that but i am trying to tell you that i was generating a barcode in a picturebox. I added more lines of my code (you can watch my code again) in which i saved that barcode image from picturebox to my desktop as a png file.

Comment: Perhaps you can find a font for your barcode? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616221/printed-barcode-isnt-clear-wpf

Comment: @kenny OP already has this one: http://www.1001fonts.com/idahc39m-code-39-barcode-font.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the barcode font is installed on your system, the following method creates a bitmap containing the barcode text:

```
private BitmapSource CreateBarcodeBitmap(string barcodeText)
{
    var text = new FormattedText(
        barcodeText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface("IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode Standard"), 20, Brushes.Black);
    var rect = new Rect(0, 0, text.Width, text.Height);
    var visual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (var drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, rect);
        drawingContext.DrawText(text, new Point());
    }

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    bitmap.Render(visual);

    return bitmap;
}
```

You could now assign the return value to the Source property of an Image element in your UI, or pass it to e.g. a `PngBitmapEncoder` to write it to a PNG file, e.g. like this:

```
var barcodeBitmap = CreateBarcodeBitmap("1234567890");
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(barcodeBitmap));

using (var fileStream = new FileStream("barcode.png", FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much i will try this and will let you know.

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the time to read online documentation of the classes used here. There is a lot to learn in WPF.